# How do i take the arpeggiated midi and get the notes/rhythms being played in logic pro?

Tags: audio, midi, logic-pro, logic, score

I arpeggiated a bass line in logic using the smart tools. I want it to show me the score for what's being played but it only shows me the chords at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean created an arpeggio of the bass line using the MIDI FX plug-in?

Comment: I don't recall how it worked but there is a youtube channel of a guy called sflogicninja where he covered how to do this sort of thing but it's an old video that was done in Logic 9.  It may still be relevant in Logic X but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the MIDI FX plug-in, then here is a simple tutorial that describes the process:

https://ask.audio/articles/capturing-the-arpeggiator-output-in-logic-pro-x

Just drag the MIDI Pattern to a MIDI/Instrument track.